# User can't go to the same places twice unless 6 months have pass

Tags: postgresql

I am an intern and this is my first job ever, so sorry for the silly question and the bad english.

```
CREATE SCHEMA code

CREATE TABLE code.place ( 
   pk_place_id VARCHAR(8), 
   place_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id PRIMARY KEY (pk_place_id)
);


CREATE TABLE code.user ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   user_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (pk_user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE code.visit ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   pk_place_id VARCHAR(8),
   data DATE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_user_id) REFERENCES code.user,
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_place_id) REFERENCES code.place
);
```

I need to make a table that shows where user can go, with the condition that it doesn't show any place that they have been in the last 6 months.

Being honest I am pretty much lost in here, I am an intern my supervisor doesn't know anything about coding (not that I know much of it), just managing people...

UPDATE:

I tried the following code.

```
SELECT *
    FROM code.visit
    WHERE data >= (curdate() - INTERVAL (1 - DAY(curdate()) DAY) -INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

But nothing happens, it doesn't even say that it is wrong, the only thing i notice is that the terminal goes from looking like:

```
code=>
code->
code->
```

To go looking like

```
code(>
code(>
code(>
```

### AND **no other code works until** I close and open the terminal.

UPDATE, it was solved it, and the things about the terminal, I just forgot to close the code with ); HAHA, thanks people.

Comment: 1. Why not use a int `id` with AutoIncrement. I assume you are making up ids currently in your code

Comment: Is there a front end to this or do you guys just use straight MySQL directly?  Also are you using Mysql or are you using Postgre ?

Comment: @easleyfixed Looks like this is Postgress if the tags are to be believed

Comment: It has both tags so I wasn't sure but you have a point there.

Comment: Hi, like it was an excel file,
I am not making the id's up, they exist. It is the citizen national ID

Comment: It is PSQL. that I am sure of it haha

Comment: The last bit of your question of how to not get the too old entries would be handled in the WHERE part of your statement and you could do a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and then format that time to add 6 months and use that value in your WHERE statement so that it doesn't return any records that have dates older than that.

Comment: How can you do a time-based query on tables where there is no time-based column ???

Comment: The third column of your table `visit` is of type `Data`, but I've never heard about that postgres type before, or is it a user-defined type ? If so what is its definition ?

Comment: No the type should be DATE, i just wrote it in my language... sorry

Comment: You can't .. you either need to add a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on each INSERT statement or UPDATE statement.  If you are using Primary Keys (which you should be) then all you have to do is add a date column and set its default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and then on your insert or update statment pass value of NULL to it for that column, and it will put  timestamp for you on each row creation or update of that table.

Comment: The thing is that this information already exist (4 years of it), so i dont think i can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP unless I start using this code  now and keep updating for 6 months, only then it would become usefull, not sure if my boss would aprove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend you check out all of the [date/time functions in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). For this problem, `age()` and intervals will be especially useful.

To get a list of place id's where the user CANNOT go:

```
-- get list of place id's where user CANNOT go
SELECT pk_place_id
  FROM code.visit
 WHERE pk_user_id = '123'
   AND age(data) <= interval '6 months'
```

To get list of places where the user CAN go, you need a list of ALL of the places minus the places the user cannot go:

```
 SELECT place_name
   FROM code.place
  WHERE pk_placed_id NOT IN (SELECT pk_place_id
                               FROM code.visit
                              WHERE pk_user_id = '123'
                                AND age(data) <= interval '6 months')
```

There's probably a clever way you could combine all three tables to give a list of all users and the places they can go, but my SQL skills are not good enough to know how do to that.